# Помощь с регулярным выражением для очистки всего, кроме цифр

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В заявке приходит телефон вида `+7(333) 333 333 3333`
для дальнейшей работы нужен он в виде `73333333333333`
Как будет выглядеть регулярка, чтобы убрать `+, (, )` и пробелы?

Comment: `$number = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как будет выглядеть ругулярка что бы убрать `+`, `(`, `)` и пробелы??

```
preg_replace("/[+\s()]/", "", $txt)
```

в целом тут регулярка не нужна, можно использовать функцию `str_replace`, которая может принимать массив выражений для замены

```
$phone = "+7(333) 333 333 3333";
$result = str_replace(['+', '(', ')', ' '], [], $phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте данное регулярное выражение.

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^0-9]+~','',$string);
```